# How do I get an html page in synchronous code without using reqwest::blocking?

Tags: rust, reqwest, yew

I need to make a function that will receive an HTML page from the link. Since I use the `yew` library, WASM does not allow me to use many custom libraries and functions. For example, the library Tokio, `future` and the function `reqwest::blocking::get()`.

I had something like this code that works in the Rust test file:

```
pub fn get_response() {
    let link = "url";
    let response = reqwest::blocking::get(link).unwrap();
    let res = response.text().unwrap();
}
```

But as I said, the `yew` library does not allow me to use `blocking::get()` how do I make the same function but without using `blocking::get()`?

Comment: There is an XY problem here. It is much more complex than what may seem to implement an HTTP client without using libraries, so it is too broad to be covered here. But what you seem to actually _need_ is a way to make HTTP requests in some WebAssembly environment. Consider [edit]ing the question accordingly (which environment, what other packages are involved, what HTTP request you wish to perform, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for translating, Nikolay. I voted to reopen, because for me the language was the main close reason. Have a look at [ask] and maybe [mre] to improve further.

Comment: So just to reiterate, your real question is *"How do I load an external website with WASM and yew?"* Maybe update your title, it currently doesn't really reflect what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have a feeling that it's not possible, as browsers forbid opening raw TCP connections from untrusted code from the internet. It would be a huge security hole if the act of opening a website could breach your firewall and open a generic TCP connection in your home network.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Yew, then your Rust code will always be running within the context of a component or in service there-of. So you should have access to a [`Context`](https://docs.rs/yew/latest/yew/html/struct.Context.html) or at least a [`Scope`](https://docs.rs/yew/latest/yew/html/struct.Scope.html) and then can issue `async` tasks like so:

```
ctx.link().send_future(async move {
    // do your reqwest call here
});
```

There are slightly different but similar functions like `.callback_future()`, `.callback_future_once()`, and `.send_future_batch()` but are really only different in terms of how they are called or how they interact with Yew. And with almost all scope functions, these will expect to return some message to the component, since you're likely to want to update some state after receiving the response.

---

If you *really* don't want to use Yew's scope functions, or don't have a reasonable way to access them, you can use `spawn_local` from the [wasm-bindgen-futures](https://crates.io/crates/wasm-bindgen-futures) crate that Yew uses internally:

```
wasm_bindgen_futures::spawn_local(async move {
    // do your reqwest call here
})
```